# Injecting a DLL from LoadImageNotifyRoutine, hangs on ZwMapViewOfSection

Tags: wdk, dll-injection, windows-kernel, kernel-mode

So I'm making a crackme and one of the parts is to hook a certain function and wait for a certain combination a params to happen, then the challenge is done.

*For that, I'm creating a driver to inject a DLL into processes that have a specific DLL and hook a certain function.*

I'm doing it by

1. Getting a handle for the DLL to inject

```
ZwCreateFile(
        &DeviceExtension->HookDllHandle, 
        GENERIC_ALL, 
        &Attributes, 
        &StatusBlock, 
        NULL, 
        0, 
        0, 
        FILE_OPEN, 
        FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT, 
        NULL, 
        0
)
```

2. Then, registering a LoadImageNotifyRoutine inside driver main 
   `PsSetLoadImageNotifyRoutine(ImageCBK);`

What's supposed to happen:

1. I check the if the needed DLL (that will export my function) is loaded.
2. By being inside the context of the process that invoked the callback, I create a section with `ZwCreateSection`, then map the dll into that section and call the DLL's entry point by creating a new thread.
3. After that, the hooking should be no problem.

**Even though the IRQL for `ZwCreateSection` and `ZwMapViewOfSection` allows their use inside a notify routine, still `ZwMapViewOfSection` hangs every time I try to use it.**

I've been using some code from [Beholder](https://github.com/stormshield/Beholder-Win32)

```
status = ObOpenObjectByPointer(PsGetCurrentProcess(), OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE, NULL, STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL, NULL, KernelMode, &ProcessHandle);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
{
    DbgPrint("Unable to get process handle\n");
    return STATUS_SEVERITY_ERROR;
}

// Create a new section for DLL mapping
InitializeObjectAttributes(&Attributes, NULL, OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE, NULL, NULL);
status = ZwCreateSection(&DllSectionHandle, SECTION_MAP_WRITE | SECTION_MAP_READ | SECTION_MAP_EXECUTE | SECTION_QUERY, &Attributes, NULL, PAGE_EXECUTE_READ, SEC_IMAGE, DeviceExtension->HookDllHandle);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
{
    ZwClose(ProcessHandle);
    DbgPrint("Section creation failed %08X\n", status);
    return status;
}
DbgPrint("Section created %08X\n", DllSectionHandle);

// Map DLL on the section
status = ZwMapViewOfSection(DllSectionHandle, ProcessHandle, &DllBaseAddress, 0, 0, NULL, &DllViewSize, ViewUnmap, 0, PAGE_EXECUTE_READ);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
{
    ZwClose(ProcessHandle);
    ZwClose(DllSectionHandle);
    DbgPrint("Unable to map section %08X\n", status);
    return status;
}
DbgPrint("Mapped DLL: %08X\n", DllBaseAddress);
```

Sadly, it never shows the last DbgPrint with the `DllBaseAddress`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply read [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/usbioctl/ns-usbioctl-_usb_node_connection_information_ex_v2)

> The operating system calls the driver's load-image notify routine at
>   `PASSIVE_LEVEL` inside a critical region with normal kernel APCs always
>   disabled

and

> To avoid deadlocks, load-image notify routines must not call system
>   routines that **map**, allocate, query, free, or perform other operations
>   on user-space virtual memory.

you ignore this and call routine `ZwMapViewOfSection` that **map**. and got deadlock

solution is simply and elegant - insert normal kernel mode APC to current thread inside `ImageCBK`. because this APC is disabled here - it executed already after you return from `ImageCBK` -just system exit from critical region and enable APC. at this point your apc KernelRoutine/NormalRoutine will be called. and exactly inside `NormalRoutine` you must map

Comment: I have tried inserting an APC, but it never got called after the routine finished. Besides that, doesn't the APC require some amount of executable virtual memory to copy actual APC function inside it?

Comment: @DenisRozimovschii - in this case you do something wrong. wrong initialize apc for example. this must be kernel mode normal apc. of course apc not require any executable memory. but driver must not be unloaded until apc not finish processing

Comment: Do you have any resources with examples of creating a kernel mode normal apc? All I've been stumbling upon are just theoretical tutorials or some game hacking forums

Comment: @DenisRozimovschii - nothing hard - first you need allocate it from nonpaged pool. than call `KeInitializeApc` with `KeGetCurrentThread()`, `OriginalApcEnvironment` `KernelMode` and not 0 `NormalRoutine`. finally you call `KeInsertQueueApc`. if your driver can be unloaded at any time - you also need reference it (driverobject) before insert apc, and have all 3 apc routines enries in asm code, which call c++ and finally exit with jmp to `ObfDereferenceObject`. but until you can do this latter

Comment: Yeah, but the three routines have to be inexecutable buffers of some sort. Don't they? Or can I just reference them like (PKNORMAL_ROUTINE)(some_func)?

Comment: @DenisRozimovschii - this routines usually inside your driver code. for what you use type cast ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178815/discussion-between-denis-rozimovschii-and-rbmm).